# Passenger Standalone - Force Redirect to SSL

Tags: passenger

I've started to use Elastic Beanstalk with Ruby + Passenger Standalone which seems awesome, however I want to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS, I haven't managed to find any resource at all about this. I've been looking at customizing the `nginx.conf.erb` but can't really find out what to do.

Note that I already have SSL working, I just need to make all requests redirecting to SSL.

Thanks,

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    my.domain.com;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen         443 ssl;
   server_name    my.domain.com;

   [....]
}
```

Comment: Edited - hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I've been using that configuration in previous projects, and it's absolutely similar to what I'm looking for, however I was more wondering if there was a passenger specific configuration to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of passenger is somewhat limited. Hope other stackoverflow users might be able to help you out!

Comment: On Github they said your way was the way to go, I used it and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: @kong put it where your nginx configuration files are. If you are confused checkout a nginx tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to late to answer this question. Just for those who need to tackle this in the future:

Try adding `"port": 80` in your Passengerfile.json, and uncommenting `"config.force_ssl = true"` in your config/environments/production.rb.

The first change will direct your browser's request (without specifying port or protocol, i.e. something like `www.example.com`) to passenger. The second line tells passenger to redirect any http request to https.